# Noun vs Gerund (Redecoration vs Redecorating)

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence..

> > "Items can be moved at ease making *redecoration* simple."

..my ever helpful computer says redecoration is misspelled. *Redecoration* is in my English-Spanish dictionary and [Webster's progeny seem to like the word just fine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redecoration) so I believe either Chrome or Apple have made a mistake in calling it out.

While it technically fits to replace it with *redecorating*, I don't like the feel of that sentence as much. I'd rather be speaking about the concept of redecorating rather than the action.

Is *redecoration* wrong or less correct?

(I suppose I'm open to total rewording as well because *simple* at the end of that sentence just sounds awkward.)

edit: Since someone pointed out the 're' is unnecessary on 'decoration,' I'll say I'm open to either spelling but issue of 're' is not integral to my question. My real question is on contrasting usage of the gerund vs a noun - '(re)decoration' vs '(re)decorating'

Comment: It was just suggested by a non-native English speaker (Japanese) friend that 'decorating' may be better because it's more specific to the action whereas 'decoration' can have the meaning of either the action or the noun. I tend to agee

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Nouns or Gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284177/using-nouns-or-gerunds)

Answer (score 1):

According to **[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/decoration?s=t)**

> **decoration**
>   [dek-uh-rey-shuh n]
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. something used for decorating; adornment; embellishment:
>
> *The gymnasium was adorned with posters and crepe-paper decorations for the dance.*
>
> 2. the act of decorating.
> 3. interior decoration.
> 4. a badge, medal, etc., conferred and worn as a mark of honor:
>      *a decoration for bravery.*

*Re-decoration* isn't recommended or preferred because it's a noun referring to the secondary definition as shown above.

> **decorate**
>   [dek-uh-reyt]
>
> **verb** (used with object), decorated, decorating
>
> 1. to furnish or adorn with something ornamental or becoming; embellish:
>
>    *to decorate walls with murals.*
> 2. to plan and execute the design, furnishings, and ornamentation of the interior of (a house, office, apartment, etc.), especially by selecting colors, fabrics, and style of furniture, by making minor structural changes, etc.:
>
>    *Their house is decorated in French Provincial style.*
> 3. to confer distinction upon by a badge, a medal of honor, etc.:
>      *to decorate a soldier for valor.*

*Re-decorate* is definitely more preferred and grammatically correct sounding.
 I do not believe one is more grammatically correct than the other, but *Re-decorating* is more preferred.

Comment: While redecoration vs decoration is helpful to know, it doesn't actually help with the decision. It sounds like you might be hinting at a preference of decorating over decoration but since you didn't actually say decorating is preferred or give any references to that, I can't tell. I did upvote because the unnecessary 're' tip is helpful.

Comment: @Tokunashi I'm not sure if you just missed it or something, but below the definition of decorate in my answer, I did put that decorating is more preferred.

Comment: Now that you've edited it to say that, yes, it does. (See your edit history from 47 seconds ago)

Comment: The only thing I edited was switching the word re-decorate to re-decorating hoping to make it more clear

Comment: @Tokunashi https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B37jLlOVcZ579gCxcybyG9uRwf3REJ0_7z9uNasAAk0/edit

Comment: So maybe I've been reading dictionaries wrong all my life. Are you saying the definitions are listed in order of importance/commonality/some hierarchy? Thus the 1st definition being different implies gerund of decorate is the preferred?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31462/discussion-between-anonymous-and-tokunashi).