# "Distributing" vs. "Distribution."

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, differences

Is there a rule when to use "distributing" instead of "distribution" or is it just a preference on which word sounds better?

Example Sentence: 
"XYZ Corp. will begin with the manufacturing and distributing of a limited number of products with expectations to expand shortly thereafter."

I think the sentence should read "distribution of" - does the word in use depend on the preposition that follows?

If I wanted to keep the word "distributing" in this sentence could I change the sentence to read: "....will begin by manufacturing and distributing a limited number of products...?"

Is the initial sentence incorrect as is or is it simply a matter of preference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Nouns or Gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284177/using-nouns-or-gerunds)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it’s a matter of preference. *Distributing* is the gerund form of *to distribute* (verbal noun), whereas *distribution* is the regular noun form. Both are nouns, so both work, although I might use *distribution*.