# Why using gerunds and infinitives as a noun when the verb has its own noun?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, gerunds, infinitives, sentence-meaning

1. **to forgive** is a great value
2. **Forgiveness** is a great value
3. **Forgiving** is a great value

Does meaning change ? And why ?
Grateful to your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Nouns or Gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284177/using-nouns-or-gerunds) The to-infinitive is rarely used as a subject (and then mostly twinned with a second infinitive), but is literary in style ('To see her is to love her').

Answer (score 0):

1. Not all verbs would comply with the -ness version. "To hit", for example.
2. "Smoking is injurious to health." -- certainly sounds better with the gerund than it would with the infinitive "to smoke". Likewise with a big set of verbs-- where "infinitivizing" them doesn't sound proper (encourage, enjoy, dread, deny, keep, etc. are some such verbs).
3. The non-finite variety of the English language amplifies its charm and were we to whittle it down to only a certain set of constructions, it wouldn't be as live and vivacious a language as it is.

Comment: Sometimes the infinitive sounds better: *to live is to suffer*, or *living is suffering*? *To obey is to enjoy* or *obeying is enjoying*? There is a slight difference in meaning between the gerund and the infinitive which means that sometimes one sounds better and sometimes the other does.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Shor for enhancing my answer. I should have used these examples to zero in on my point, but thanks nonetheless! :)

Comment: Grateful to your help

Answer (score -1):

You ask a subtle question. I will try to give the sense of the slight differences that I see. I hope others will forgive me if they see things differently. I already forgive them for their inevitable criticisms!

1. *The action of forgiving* is a great value
2. *The personal quality of a tendency (or inclination) to forgive* is a great value
3. *Any specific act of forgiveness* is of great value.

Comment: Grateful to your help

Comment: Kind of you. But perhaps the person who marked it down would like to give their reasons? We may learn something from them.