# "depends upon developing" vs "depends upon development"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, test

This is an English test item:

The human eye is nature's most fantastic organ, and the high degree of development of human society probably depends upon ......... .

a) developing of this organ

b) the development of this organ

Which choice is correct? And why is the other one not correct?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Nouns or Gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284177/using-nouns-or-gerunds) '... the developing' would be grammatical, but 'the development' is the better choice here as the finished degree of development in man rather than the assumed evolutionary process (which the ing-form would point to) is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure "b" -- "the development of." The sentence is talking about the high level of functioning of the eye, and "the development of" refers to a complete (or almost complete) level of evolution of something.

Comment: Hello, Lillie. The reason I didn't give an 'answer' was because the pure noun vs ing-form issue has been covered before.