# God's existing vs God's existence

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Can we say something like "I am thankful for God's existing" rather than "...thankful for God's existence?"

Why do we never hear this?

I am thinking along the lines of: "She doesn't approve of me going out" vs. "She doesn't approve of my going out"

Can there be gerund(?) sentences that have nothing after them - like "existing" or "She doesn't approve of my knowing"?

Comment: Participles have a spectrum of meaning that covers both ends, that is to say the noun function and the verbal function. Depending on _how_ they are used adds _movement_ to a _state_. See elsewhere on this site regarding participles : it is a worthwhile study.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Nouns or Gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284177/using-nouns-or-gerunds) In your examples, using the POSS-ing structure would be grammatical, but would sound rather highfalutin, high-flown. If there is a regular noun, it is usually better to stick with it unless there is a good reason not to. Note also that the ACC-ing structure  "She doesn't approve of me going out" is a red herring here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry what does POSS and ACC refer to? And why is that example a red herring?

Comment: @JKusin The POSS-ing structure uses a possessive determiner to indicate the logical subject of an *-ing* verb (a form of nonfinite clause), for example as in ***his** calling the shots*. The ACC-ing structure uses an object pronoun (think "accusative case") in that same position, for example as in ***him** calling the shots*. Both mean the same thing but the POSS form is mostly to be found only in writing not in speech, which prefers the ACC form. Some matrix verbs require a specific version here and forbid the other, e.g. *I heard him calling Mother from upstairs.*

Comment: (1) John Lawler explains this at the duplicate mentioned first (the third addresses the choice between the regular noun and the ing-form). (2) Your question asks about the difference between regular noun and ing-form usage in a possessive structure ('**I am thankful for God's** _existence / existing_.') The ACC-ing form (eg 'I was unsure at that time about God existing') wouldn't work well in your example, and doesn't allow a straight swap (*'I was unsure at that time about God existience.')

Comment: Your last sentence asks a different question. "She doesn't approve of my knowing" is OK if rather rarefied (possibly pretentious-sounding). Ditto, though less rarefied, for "She doesn't approve of me knowing" (here, the emphasis is '_me in particular_ knowing').